# How to get files from google drive by theirs ids in single request

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

Im trying to get few (20-25) files from GoogleDrive via [files.list API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) by theirs ids. I got full list, then filter it and want to get filted list with full metadata paged and limited.

But looks like there is no ability to do it in one request: **files.get** accepts only one ID param, **files.list** search doesn't allow to pass id into it.

Any ideas how to filter files by **set of ids**?

Comment: @steve-bazyl make attention please

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit support for this specific operation.  You can batch arbitrary requests together using [gapi.client.HttpBatch](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientHttpBatch)